# Derivative for $4x^2+\frac{216}{x}$ .

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$4x^2+\frac{216}{x}$ .

Steps that I used was to differentiate the the first term using formula .
2nd step was that 216 is a constant and we don’t differentiate values which are present in denominator.
Therefore 1/x.

It’s differentiation came to be equal to this by me.

I got is $8x + \frac{1}{x}$

But the answer is $8x-\frac{216}{x^2}$.

How come the constant is not differentiated and x value got squared ?

Comment: Can you show your own steps for differentiating second term?

Comment: I agree with cosmo5. You have an opportunity to improve your differentiation skills, if you share your work now.

Comment: I too agree.Thank you for the offer.I have written the steps that I did.

Comment: Please what I wrote.Is that wrong way to solve .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{x}=x^{-1}$, hence

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}=(-1)x^{-2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $c$ is a constant, then $(cf(x))'=c(f(x))'$; you get the square because $\frac{1}{x}=x^{-1}$ and $(x^{-1})'=(-1)\cdot x^{-2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$.
To obtain the correct result you have to use these two rules.